# Opening _blank links in Electron Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating a web browser with Electron (please don't answer that that is "pointless", "not smart", etc.). When my user navigates to a link with the `_blank` attribute, I want a new Electron Web Browser window to open. Or, as a second choice, open the URL in their default web browser (such as Chrome, Edge, Opera, etc.).

I've looked at several other StackOverflow questions but with zero luck every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const { app, BrowserWindow, shell } = require("electron"); 
   ...
   mainWindow.webContents.on("new-window", (_, url) => {
        _.preventDefault();
        const protocol = require("url").parse(url).protocol;
        if (protocol === "http:" || protocol === "https:") {
            shell.openExternal(url);
        }
    });
```

This event listener will trigger the callback whenever the user attempts to open the URL on your renderer. This callback will open your target URL on the default browser.

And regarding your other approach, I'd recommend not opening a new electron browser instance for accessing the target URL. This will be the cause of heavy resource usage.

Comment: I tried adding them in my renderer and main files, which both didn't work.

Comment: This should be on your main and it should be working. :(